# Chromium always opens popups in the center of the screen regardless of options specified

Tags: chromium, javascript

On my pi, Chromium always opens in the center of the screen.  I discovered this when trying to open a popup at a specific location on the screen using the following javascript:

window.open("some url", "_blank", "left=xxx,top=xxx")

This works great on a Windows device but when I move the html file to my pi, the window always opens centered on the screen.